# Dependency injection with associated types causing arguments without type names (undescores) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, dependency-injection, associated-types

The situation is following: I'm using a protocol to inject dependencies and the best way I found to implement this in Swift is to use the `associatedtype` keyword. I am also using protocol composition since some implementations of `TestProtocol` need more than one dependency.

```swift
protocol TestProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Dependencies
    func inject(_ dependency: Dependencies)
}

protocol HasSomething {
    var something: Something { get set }
}

protocol HasSomethingElse {
    var somethingElse: SomethingElse { get set }
}
```

To use this I found that I'll need to use generics like this:

```swift
class TestService<T> where T: TestProtocol, T.Dependencies == TestService {

    weak var testProtocol: T?

    init(with testProtocol: T) {
        self.testProtocol = testProtocol        
        self.testProtocol?.inject(self)
    }
}
```

Now when I want to use this service somewhere else and I'm trying to initiate it I get following problem:

[image: problem with generics]

The parameter is displayed as `_` and not as the protocol name `TestProtocol`.

Let's say I would use this code in a library. How would a user know (without reading the documentation of course) what type could be used in this context when he is not even knowing what protocol he has to implement?

Is there a better way on how to use dependency injection with the type actually being displayed to the user, or am I doing something wrong in the `where` clause of the `TestService` class, or is this simply not possible in the current versions of Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, this is simply not possible.

```swift
class TestService<T> where T: TestProtocol
```

The `where` clause means `T` could be anything, with the constraint that the given object **must** conform to `TestProtocol`.

The Xcode autocomplete feature only displays the **resolved type** when available, but it doesn't show the constraints on a generic, and unfortunately there is nothing you can do about that.

You have the exact same issue in the swift standard library, with `Dictionary` for example

```swift
public struct Dictionary<Key, Value> where Key : Hashable {

  public init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, Value)...) {
    // ..
  }
}
```

The generic `Key` as a constraint to `Hashable`, but Xcode still shows `_` in the autocomplete list.

[image: Dictionary<_, _> (dictionaryLiteral: (_, _)...)]

I guess Swift developers are use to this behaviour, so it won't be a big issue, even if your code is embedded in a library.

> How would a user know (without reading the documentation of course) what type could be used in this context when he is not even knowing what protocol he has to implement?

Because Xcode is pretty clear about the protocol requirement.
If I try to initialize the `TestService` with a `String` I'll get the error:

```
Referencing initializer 'init(with:)' on 'TestService' requires that 'String' conform to 'TestProtocol'
```

Which is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually at the time of  `init(with testProtocol: T)` Compiler doesn't know about `T` of course  because it is generic

if you provide directly class it will show you in suggestion

For example

```
class TestService<T:Something>  {

    weak var testProtocol: T?

    init(with testProtocol: T) {
        self.testProtocol = testProtocol
    }

}
```

Now you will see compiler know that it need `SomeThing` at `T`

[image]

---

For your case For `TestProtocol` You can replace **with**   with something user readable world. for next time compiler will give you provided type as suggestion

For  Example

```
class TestService<T:TestProtocol>  {

    weak var testProtocol: T?

    init(with testProtocol: T) {
        self.testProtocol = testProtocol
    }

    func add(t:T) {

    }
}

class Test {

    init() {
        let t = Something()

        let ts = TestService(with: t)



    }
}
```

In `Test` class you can type ts.add now it knows

[image]

Comment: Yes but when initialising it still shows _. It only shows the name of the protocol after the `init`